# Parse beforeSave delete user's previous post(s)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Read the title, when user creates Post, it should delete previous posts. It's not working.

`Pheed` contains `user` and `comment` fields.

Update: Now `Can't Serialize an unsaved Parse Object` is returned with new code under here.

Update: New Answer works but only using `afterSave` which deletes all, need to retain the most recent status/comment somehow

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Pheed", function(request, response) {

                   var user = new Parse.User({id:request.user.username});
                   var query = new Parse.Query("Pheed");
                   query.equalTo("user", user);

                   query.find({
                              success: function(results) {
                              for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                              results[i].destroy({});
                              };
                              results.save();
                              response.success();
                              }
                              ,

                             error: function(object, error) {
                             response.error();
                             }

                    }); // find
                });// beforeSave
```

Comment: If you're going to save a new object and new references and delete the old one, why don't you just overwrite the object that is already set up?

Comment: well I would but the code in my app already creates a new object. Need a quick and dirty solution for iOS app pending review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using Promises, and the .each method on Parse.Query.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Pheed", function(request, response) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Pheed");
  // Assuming "user" is a Pointer column of to ParseUser (_User)
  query.equalTo("user", request.user);
  query.each(function (obj) {
    return obj.destroy();
  }).then(function() {
    response.success('Deleted all Pheeds for this user.');
  });

}
```

Comment: using afterSave works, but I would like to retain the most recent status, which is does not right now.

Answer (score 0):

1) Get params from request.params.  2) Does the user column on "Pheed" really contain a username?  It would be better to have a pointer to user (and the column name would make more sense).

If so, send the user.objectId with the request, then...

```
var user = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userId});
var query = new Parse.Query("Pheed");
query.equalTo("user", user);
```

If the "Pheed" object really keeps the username, then you can do this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Pheed");
query.equalTo("user", request.params.username);
```

Comment: using `request.params.user` returns a error on `user`, that's why i didn't originally use it.

Comment: no but it has to equal the actual `username`, i changed it to `request.user.username`, now i get `Can't serialize an unsaved Parse Object`, better?